# Unable to show current PHP data in Javascript Popup

Tags: javascript, php, html

1. I have a PHP function that iterates through every user post in my database and displays them on the page.
2. Each post has an edit button in a dropdown menu that triggers a JavaScript popup menu which should show the user post text so they can edit it.
3. I have posts 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'.  Each is being displayed in a unique postbox listed below.  Every edit button will display 'd's' text instead of their own respective text data.
4. My question is how can I get the correct information to correspond to each post?  I have tried inserting PHP Variables into the Javascript call function without success.
5. Popup-1 Should probably be Popup-'.$PostID.' or something, but I'm not sure.  The HTML Code listed below is inside a While Loop that goes through each post in the Database.  So In the snippet there is one post, but on my end there are several posts.  Still trying to figure out how snippets work.

```js
function togglePopup(){

    document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.popup .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.popup .content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    height: 220px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
    display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
        <h1>Edit Post</h1>
        <p>'.$Text.'</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="postBox">
    <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
    <p class="postusername">'.$UserName.'<p>
    <p class="posttime">'.date('M jS, Y h:ia',strtotime($Date)).'<p>
    <p>'.$Text.'<p>
    <br>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">···</button>
        <div Id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">                                        
            <a href="#View">View</a>
            <a href="#Like">Like</a>
            <a href="#Save">Save</a>
            <a href="../editpost">Edit</a>
            <button onclick="togglePopup()">Popup</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me everytime:

```
<?php
include('scripts/connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `argument` = 'value'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '
      <!-- Your HTML Code -->
      <h1>To insert the PHP data use: '.$row['databaseRowName'].'</h1>
      ';
   }
} else {
   echo "Oops there are currently no data in database";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

It needs to be $row['rowName'] to be passed from the database.